# Protractor not starting multiple instances

Tags: angular, protractor

Given the following protractor config:

```
...
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    maxInstances: 2,
    sharedTestFiles: true,
},
suites: {
    suite1: ['first.spec.js'],
    suite2: ['second.spec.js'],
}
...
```

I expected web driver to launch multiple instances of chrome and run the first.spec.js and second.spec.js simultaneously. However, it just launches one chrome instance. Is there any other config that needs to be set to make this scenario work?

I have also tried using multiCapabilities which is launching multiple instances but all those instances run the same tests. This is not what I want. I want to have specs running simultaneously split across the multiple instances.

I am using

```
"protractor": "^7.0.0",
```

Comment: Everything looks correct to me except that the filenames listed under suites should be strings or arrays of strings. What command are you using to kick off the tests?

Comment: ya file names are indeed strings in my actual config. I am running via intellij. I think it runs protractor protractor.conf.js

Comment: also tried npm start and npm run and got same results.

Comment: Oh, under capabilities it looks like you have `sharedTestFiles` and it should be `shardTestFiles`. Is that correct in your config too? Missed it the first time.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem indeed, I need to get my sight tests done soon :(